# How to create service for non parent-child Angular 2 components

Tags: angular, service

I'm really stuck with creating a service for "unrelated" Angular 2 components. There are no problems, however, with parent-child relations (I use binding or event emitter).

I have 3 files:

1. StatsService which should carry data.
2. MatchBoard component which generates football shots
3. StatsComponent which prints number of shots to the screen.

But I've been dealing with this for hours now, having read the official A2 documentation and still cannot figure out a solution.

WHAT I WANT: I just want to generate shots (every 2 sec), grab them with the service and send into StatsComponent so that it displays the number of shots on the screen. That simple.

The StatsService component

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class StatsService {
  private homeTeamShots = new Subject<any>();
  homeTeamShots$ = this.homeTeamShots.asObservable();
  publishData(data:any){
    this.homeTeamShots.next(data);
  }

}
```

MatchBoard component

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import {StatsService} from '../stats.component/stats.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'match-board',
  templateUrl: './matchboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./matchboard.component.css']
})

export class MatchBoard implements OnChanges {
  homeTeamShots:number = 0;
  constructor(private _statsService:StatsService) {
    this._statsService.homeTeamShots$.subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('matchboard received this: ' + data);
      }
    )
  }
  ngOnChanges(){

  }

  onHomeTeamShot(){
    this.homeTeamShots += 1;
    this._statsService.publishData(this.homeTeamShots);
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    // shots are taken every 2 seconds as a example
    setInterval(()=> this.onHomeTeamShot(), 2000);
  }

}
```

And StatsComponent

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import {StatsService} from '../stats.component/stats.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'stats',
  templateUrl: './stats.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stats.component.css'],
  providers: [StatsService]
})
export class StatsComponent implements OnChanges {
  homeTeamShots:number;
  constructor(private _statsService:StatsService) {
    this.homeTeamShots = 0;
    this._statsService.homeTeamShots$.subscribe(
      data => {
        this.homeTeamShots = data;
        console.log('Sibling2Component-received from sibling1: ' + data);
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnChanges(){

  }

  onHomeTeamShot() {
    this.homeTeamShots += 1;
    console.log('number of shots in stats now ' + this.homeTeamShots);
    this._statsService.publishData(this.homeTeamShots);
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    setInterval(()=> console.log(this.homeTeamShots), 2050);
  }
}
```

In the console, I get **'matchboard received this: 2 (then 3, then 4 like normal)'** from the MatchBoard component. 
But the problem begins in StatsComponent - it gets stuck right after 'subscribe' and logs just '0' all the time.

I tried calling onHomeTeamShot() somewhere in statsComponent but it shows '1' all the time from the beginning and does not change either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the line

```
providers: [StatsService]
```

in the StatsComponent. That means the StatsComponent has an own instance of the service.
The solution is to have the provider in the component above the three components only and remove the line from StatsComponent.

You can find some more information about that here: https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection

Comment: Omg, I didn't even notice that... Wasted 12 hours... :) thank you very much! It works now.

Answer (score 1):

Shift all your logic to the service, and leverage the power of `Observables` to do the heavy lifting.

In your service, create an Observable using `.interval()`. This will take care of your polling. You do not even need the `publishData()` since you are already using a `Subject`. I created a function called `generateShots()`

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject}    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class StatsService {
    private homeTeamShots = new Subject<any>();
    homeTeamShots$ = this.homeTeamShots.asObservable();

    generateShots() {
        return Observable.interval(2000)
            .map(ticks => this.homeTeamShots$.next(ticks));
             //.interval() returns a single integer, starting from 0,1,2....
             //just simply update your subject with that value.
    }

}
```

Now, to "start" countdown in your `MatchBoard` component, simply subscribe to `generateShots()`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._statsService.generateShots()
        .subscribe(shots => this.homeTeamShots = shots);
    //this.homeTeamShots will increment from 0 to 1,2,3.... every 2000ms
}
```

And to display your shots in `StatsComponent`, subscribe to your `homeTeamShots$` `Subject`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._statsService.homeTeamShots$.subscribe(
        data => {
            this.homeTeamShots = data;
            console.log('Sibling2Component-received from sibling1: ' + data);
        }
    );
}
```

And voila, you got two components syncing the data through a single shared service (singleton). Clean.

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to Reactive stuff and Angular but I will try to learn by doing :) I will really redo the app to handle things via service